# Double HTTP-Status header on HTTP-POST to Jersey

Tags: java, http, jersey, grizzly

I wrote a simple Grizzly/Jersey application, which you can find here:

https://github.com/boldt/stackoverflow-14526627

I want to post some form data:

```
curl -X POST -F "name=test" -i http://localhost:9999/files
```

I'm getting the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 25 Jan 2013 16:51:18 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

As you can see, the header is doubled, first a `100 Continue` followed by a `200 OK`. Is doesn't makes sense to get the `100 Continue`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal.  Curl is following the HTTP 1.1 spec.  You are doing a POST which means you are going to be sending data to the server.  Curl is sending a request header to the server with "Expect: 100-continue" in it.

This tells the server that the client wants permission to send a POST document and if the server responds with HTTP/1.1 100 Continue, then client sends the document (your form pairs in this case) otherwise the server may reject it for whatever reason with HTTP/1.1 417 Expectation Failed and this allows the client to not waste time sending lots of data possibly if it will be rejected.

Comment: I'll have a look to the spec and wireshark to check it out :)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the two headers.
Read about the Expect header.
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
Check your request headers. You are probably sending HTTP Expect with curl.

```
curl -vv -X POST -F "name=test" -i http://localhost:9999/files
```

Comment: Your're right. Curl is adding Expect, as soon I'm adding `-F`. See: http://the-stickman.com/web-development/php-and-curl-disabling-100-continue-header/

Comment: And you can see this (expect: 100-continue) when you turn on your server-side logging in Jersey.